# How to use reactjs with chart-js-rails in a Rails 4 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

So I'm very new to reactjs and using chart-js-rails gem and react-rails gem in a Rails 4 application.  In componentDidMount method I want to essentially create a bar chart.  The data is getting fetched correctly as I can see it in the React chrome dev tools.

The issue is that I get error *chart_container.self-40c721a….js?body=1:17 Uncaught TypeError: barNode.getContext is not a function*.  This means somehow the ReactDOM.findDOMNode() is not returning an element that I can perform getContext("2d") on.

1 - Is it possible to use jQuery/Javascript and mix it with React this way to create a Chart.js bar chart in the CView component which will then be rendered in the Container component class?
2 - If no to #1, then what should I do to create a chart?

```
@Container = React.createClass

  # set initial state before mounting component
  getInitialState: ->
    # set to true once data has been fetched
    getData: false
    # The data JSON array used to display the data in the view
    someData: []

  #some other code here...

  componentDidUpdate: ->
    barNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(@refs.barChart)
    barChart = new Chart(barNode.getContext("2d")).Bar(@state.someData)

  render: ->
    <div>
      <CView ref="barChart" data={@state.someData} />
    </div>

@CView = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <p data={@props.data}></p>
```